# Programmatically logout user without redirect

Tags: 7, users

I have the following code in my module:

```
<?php

function MODULENAME_init() {
        if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
                global $user;
                $user = user_load(31);
                user_login_finalize();
        }
}
```

Purpose of this code is to log in all anonymous user as user with id 31. But with this code i can't even logout correctly:

```
if (user_is_logged_in() && request_uri() == '/user') {
    user_logout();
}
```

After i am visiting http://ggames.kz/user i am getting redirected back to the main page and so i am logged again as user 31. I want to log out any user when he's requesting http://ggames.kz/user and show a login form in order to log in as user with id 1.

Comment: I guess, your code in `hook_init` is the reason you can't log out. Because once you logout, it log in you back.

Comment: The really interesting question is, why the auto-login is necessary? Maybe it's possible to find a better solution for this, once being able to understand your intentions on auto-login.

Comment: Also, notice that http://ggames.kz/user is used from users to access their user page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your hook code.

```
function MODULENAME_init() {
  if (!user_is_logged_in() && request_uri() != '/user') {
    // Log in the user as user #31.
  }
  elseif (user_is_logged_in() && request_uri() == '/user') {
    module_load_include('pages.inc', 'user');
    user_logout();
  }
}
```

Since `user_logout()` is defined in modules/user/user.pages.inc, you need to first load that file, and then call that function, or you will get an error about a not defined function. You don't need to first check the file has been already included, since it will not be included twice.

Keep in mind that http://ggames.kz/user could be directly accessed from users to see their user page, and that Drupal redirect logged-in users who try to access http://ggames.kz/user/login to http://ggames.kz/user.

Comment: Thanks, i am awared about this. Now when i visit http://ggames.kz/user (first time it loads as expected - auth form) second time - i am getting an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_logout()"

Comment: Right, I forgot the function is not defined in a module.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Your load is off a bit, should be `module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');`

Comment: @Clive Yep, I inverted two arguments. But I could also use `module_load_include('pages.inc', 'user')`.